# Save form input in excel. Downloadable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a form and tried to export the input of the form to save it as excel in server. I get error in the PHP file that I have done.

Can you please check this PHP and help me what i made a mistake or is there any shortcut for the same?

The form that created is `praths.in`

This is the PHP :

```
{?php

$clientname=$_POST{'field1'};
$phonenumber=$_POST{'field2'};
$followupdate=$_POST{'field3'};
$branchname=$_POST{'field4'};
$leadfrom=$_POST{'field5'};
$planname=$_POST{'field6'};
$expectedpremium=$_POST{'field7'};
$remaks=$_POST{'field8'};
$crmupdated=$_POST{'CRM-Update'};
$smname=$_POST{'field9'};
$branchname=$_POST{'field10'};
$staffname=$_POST{'field11'};
$discussionheld=$_POST{'field12'};

$data=$field1.",".$field2,".$field3,".$field4,".$field5,".$field6,".$field7,".$field8,".$CRM-Update,".$field9,".$field10,".$field11,".$field12;


$file="file.csv";


file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
print "{h1 align=center}Thank you for submitting data!{/h1}";


?}
{html}
{head}
{title}ThankYou Page{/title}
{/head}
{body}
{h1}{a href="index.html"}GO BACK{/a} {/h1}

{/body}




{/html}
```

Comment: Can you please add the information what error you get or what does not work.

Comment: {?php $clientname=$_POST{'field1'}; $phonenumber=$_POST{'field2'}; $followupdate=$_POST{'field3'}; $branchname=$_POST{'field4'}; $leadfrom=$_POST{'field5'}; $planname=$_POST{'field6'}; $expectedpremium=$_POST{'field7'}; $remaks=$_POST{'field8'}; $crmupdated=$_POST{'CRM-Update'}; $smname=$_POST{'field9'}; $branchname=$_POST{'field10'}; $staffname=$_POST{'field11'}; $discussionheld=$_POST{'field12'}; $data=$field1.",".$field2,".$field3,".$field4,".$field5,"

Comment: I get error like this..